# Add a job to the joblist in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting, actionfunction

I am having a list of jobs in the Visualforce controller. And in the page, I have a button called Add job, which adds another job into the list.

What it current did is using an actionFunction for the add job button which adds another job into the list and then rerender the page. It works fine but there will be a significant delay each time the customer clicks the add job button. Especially after placing the page idle for some time.

So I am thinking of placing the add job logic into client side only and generate the list only when submitting the whole form. The solution I can think of is to store things in the client side only which means no connection with the variables in the controller and use a javascript remoting to handle that before form submission.

This seems to be a viable solution to me but not very 'direct' and also kind of means rewriting the whole page. Is there a more 'direct' way of resolving this? No is a perfectly acceptable answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is exact use case for using some kind of Javascript framework to make it smoother and faster

**Pure Javascript**

Using pure Javascript would mean lot of code writing and building from scratch

**Use Jquery**

Using jquery library would simplify this a bit since most of code would be handled by library itself and all that you will need to discover is hook the data into this

**Using Angular**

Personally i am bug fan of using angular here as the concept of Two way data binding and adding a Scope would solve this with minimum amount of effort

Already you can find some code online right away [Sample Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Cowwando/5dn2mtb8/)

In short its what you are most confident of you can pick this but yes using framework like Angular or React should simplify this lot for you .